# Filter array based on string content and repetition count with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

I will explain what's needed. Hopefully, you can help.
I have an array. First, two numbers are weight that doesn't matter, followed by whitespace and an **email**.

```
var arr= new Array("10 firstemail@email.com","15 secondemail@email.com","25 secondemail@email.com","35 secondemail@email.com","15 firstemail@email.com"); // huge array with many emails not just 2
```

I want a new array, **filtered by the email, which repeats the least times.**

it should be:

```
["10 firstemail@email.com","15 firstemail@email.com"];
```

because firstemail@email.com repeats only 2 times while secondemail@email.com repeats 3 times.

Used browser is IE8 with jQuery (must use jQuery because native .filter() is not working)

I know this could probably be done with several foreach/fors but I'm looking for an optimized solution.

For example:

```
new_arr = $(arr).filter(function (str) { return arr[str].indexOf("firstemail@email.com") >=0; });
```

This works if you know that firstemail@email.com repeats the least in the array but this is no solution because I don't know which email repeats the least times.. probably Math.min could be used somehow but I would be happy for the help.

**EDIT: Please take a look at this code**

```
var arr= new Array("10 firstemail@email.com","15 secondemail@email.com","25 secondemail@email.com","35 secondemail@email.com","15 firstemail@email.com"); // huge array with many emails not just 2

function extractEmails (text) { return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); } // Please edit the regEx to get least repeated email instead all

var get_least_repeated=extractEmails(arr.toString());

new_arr = $(arr).filter(function (str) { return arr[str].indexOf(get_least_repeated) >=0; });

console.log(new_arr);
```

This seems to work the best but I'm not good at regEx at all to alter the extractEmails function to get the least repeating email (currently gets all)

Another idea is to use jQuery.grep() somehow.

**EDIT 2:** I came up with my own optimized code with the idea of @arielb to have object with email as key and duplicate count as value.

Final code

```
var arr = new Array(
  "15 secondemail@email.com",
  "10 firstemail@email.com",
  "25 secondemail@email.com",
  "35 secondemail@email.com",
  "15 firstemail@email.com",
 "12 third@email.com",
 "35 secondemail@email.com"
); // huge array with many emails nut just 2


    var new_emails={}; //init an object
$.each(arr,function(k,v){
  var justmail=v.split(" ")[1];
  if(typeof(new_emails[justmail])=='undefined') new_emails[justmail]=0;
  new_emails[justmail]+=1; 
  });

var selectedemail=''; var eminvalue=Number.MAX_VALUE;
$.each(new_emails,function(k,v){
if(v<eminvalue) {eminvalue=v;selectedemail=k;}
});

var new_arr=$(arr).filter(function (str) { return arr[str].indexOf(selectedemail) >=0; });

console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: Instead of using regex to match emails (known to be problematic), why not match some digits and some whitespace at the beginning of the string (much easier to match `^\d+\s+`)? You could also just use `map`: `arr = arr.map(text => text.replace(/^\d+\s+/, ''))` which will give you an array of just the emails. Then, I would use `reduce` for the rest of it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey good point on the regex.. This is just example. The thing is that I believe regEx is powerful enough to count the repetitions and pick the one that repeats the least and avoid loops over array. Also don't forget there's IE8 limitation which does not support native .map

Comment: Well, there are polyfills for `map` and `reduce`. I would question IE8's regex power as well. Note that IE8 is no longer supported by Microsoft, so there should be some serious security discussions being had regarding that browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an object\dictionary for counting the number of occurrences of each email, without any filter.
maybe something like this:

```
    function check(arr){
    var emails={}; //init an object
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     emails[arr[i]]=++emails[arr[i]] || 1;
    }
    //now we are going to check which email is the least.
    var arrOccurences = [];
    var minValue = arr.length;
    var selectedEmail = '';
    jQuery.each(emails,function(key,value){
     if(value<minValue){
       selectedEmail=key;
       minValue = value;
    }

    });
    console.log(selectedEmail);
  }
```

Comment: 2 fors and 1 each.. 
The array is huge so this is lacking performance. Thank you anyways.

Comment: the each is over the emails dictionary , it will iterate only over the unique emails.
the big 0 is still O(N)

Comment: @Svetoslav I have removed one for, now you have only one for the whole array and the other forEach is for the unique email addresses only so its clearly less than N.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

```
var arr= new Array(
  "10 firstemail@email.com",
  "15 secondemail@email.com",
  "25 secondemail@email.com",
  "35 secondemail@email.com",
  "15 firstemail@email.com"); // huge array with many emails nut just 2

// Collect each unique email with its count
// and an array of each occurrence of the email
// in the original array
var emails = {};
$.each(arr, function(index, str) {
  var email = str.split(' ')[1];
  if (!emails[email]) {
    emails[email] = {values: [], count: 0}
  }
  emails[email].values.push(str);
  emails[email].count++;
});

var emailCounts = [];
// Create an array with unique emails and their counts
$.each(emails, function(email, data) {
  emailCounts.push([email, data.count])
})

// Sort the unique emails by count
emailCounts.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

// First element in the sorted array is the least frequent
var leastFrequentEmail = emailCounts[0][0];

console.log(emails[leastFrequentEmail].values)
```

https://jsbin.com/milemugota/edit?js,console

It iterates once over the full Array and then twice (once to collect the counts and once for sorting) over the unique array.

### Option 2

Following Algorithm 1 from https://www.sneppets.com/java/find-least-common-element-in-unsorted-array/

```
function emailPart(str) {
  return str.split(' ')[1];
}

var arr = new Array(
  "10 firstemail@email.com",
  "15 secondemail@email.com",
  "25 secondemail@email.com",
  "35 secondemail@email.com",
  "15 firstemail@email.com"); // huge array with many emails nut just 2

// sort by email
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var emailA = emailPart(a);
  var emailB = emailPart(b)
  if (emailA > emailB) {
    return 1;
  } else if (emailA < emailB) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
})

var currentEmailCount = 1;
var minEmailCount = arr.length + 1;
var leastCommonEmail = emailPart(arr[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (emailPart(arr[i]) == emailPart(arr[i - 1])) {
    currentEmailCount++;
  } else {
    if (currentEmailCount < minEmailCount) {
      minEmailCount = currentEmailCount;
      leastCommonEmail = emailPart(arr[i - 1])
    }
    currentEmailCount = 1;
  }
}

if (currentEmailCount < minEmailCount) {
  leastCommonEmail = emailPart(arr[arr.length - 1]);
}

console.log(leastCommonEmail)
```

https://jsbin.com/gitacoqipa/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works but a more neat and faster solution would be (I think) : before arr being actually array - it was string.Maybe we can regex that string really good and get least repeated email ? You can use extractEmails(arr.toString())
------
function extractEmails (text) { return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi); } 

So this would return all emails.. what if just least repeated one? Then I will use it with the mentioned filter function.

Comment: I can't think of a way to accomplish it with just a regex to return the least occurring email

Comment: Thanks for option 2 as well. I think I will mark you as solution if nobody comes up with the regex idea or something faster because the array is really huge and the least manipulation the better.